# processing row combinations from a array and output in multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, combinations

I have an array of values like this:

0129 4589 4878 7895

I would like to iterate through the entire array and leave one row out in each turn to have this:

0129 4589 4878

0129 4589 7895

0129 4878 7895

4589 4878 7895

.... and so forth

I am aware of the itertools 'combinations' in python. Is there away I can apply the funciton to a whole row of the array rather than indivdual values of a row?

Comment: What is a "row"? What is an "array"? Can you be more specific? Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer I think

```
itertools.combinations(array, 3)
```

would produce this output

i.e.,

```
>>> [x for x in itertools.combinations([123,345,543,234],3)]
[(123, 345, 543), (123, 345, 234), (123, 543, 234), (345, 543, 234)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful, I just had restructure my thinking about a function.